# What does 'be done' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> “Seize him! SEIZE HIM!” shrieked Voldemort again, and Quirrell
>   lunged, knocking Harry clean off his feet landing on top of him, both
>   hands around Harry’s neck — Harry’s scar was almost blinding him with
>   pain, yet he could see Quirrell howling in agony. 
>    “Master, I
>   cannot hold him — my hands — my hands!” 
>    And Quirrell, though
>   pinning Harry to the ground with his knees, let go of his neck and
>   stared, bewildered, at his own palms — Harry could see they looked
>   burned, raw, red, and shiny. 
>    “Then kill him, fool, and **be
>   done**!” screeched Voldemort. 
>  Quirrell raised his hand to
>   perform a deadly curse, but Harry, by instinct, reached up and grabbed
>   Quirrell’s face —
>    “AAAARGH!” 
>  (Harry Potter and the
>   Sorcerer's Stone)

‘Be done’ seems to mean ‘Kill the boy’. But I can’t understand the structure of ‘be + adjective’, which seems not take object. What does the phrase mean, and how do I understand the structure?

Comment: ""kill him" means "kill the boy", "be done" does not. The latter means what it says ... once Harry is dead, Quirrel is done and need not worry about holding him or anything else about him. "be + adjective" is quite common: be quiet, be happy, be enlightened, be angry, be surprised ... it's not clear what your difficulty is with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“Be” is an [imperative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood). You've probably encountered that construction with other adjectives such as “be quiet” (act in such a manner as not to make noise), “be still” (act in such a manner as not to move), “be on time” (act in such a manner as not to be late), …

The adjective “done” means finished with a particular action. “Be done” is an idiom. If you take it literally, it means either “arrange to have finished now”, which cannot be done, or “arrange to have finished in the future”, which would mean “do it”. What “be done” actually means is “finish this soon”: it's a command to complete a task quickly.

In this passage, Voldemort is unhappy that Quirrell is taking too much time killing Harry, and instructing him to finish the task so that they can move on to do other things.

Comment: We sometimes see a longer version of this; namely, ["and be done **with it**"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/and_be_done_with_it).